# How should Greater Turning work under Complete Divine's alternate Turning rules?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, house-rules, class-feature, prestige-class

I'm building a Cleric for a D&D 3.5 game who I plan to eventually take levels in the Radiant Servant of Pelor prestige class. In that game we've been using Complete Divine's alternate rules for Turning Undead- basically damaging undead in a radius instead of making a check to see how many undead you affect and how severely. Thing is, those rules don't say anything about Greater Turning, which RSoP gets as a class feature pretty early on. Does anyone have or know of any house-rules for using Greater Turning by the alternate Turning rules? I personally would imagine something along the lines of "fort save for full damage, die if fail", but I just wanted some input first before presenting my case to the DM.

Comment: I change the affected creatures rule. I have whatever undead creatures can be turned, the HD that the priest rolls, roll Will DC checks vs the priest. If the priest is higher level than the creature he gets a +1 for every 2 lvls higher and if the undead is higher then vise verse.

Comment: By "Destroy Undead" do you mean the greater turning granted power of the the sun Domain (*PH* 188) and the radiant servant of Pelor's special ability extra greater turning (*CD* 52), or do you mean something else?

Comment: I meant Greater Turning. I'll edit the article to refelct that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Variant Turning Rules: Destruction of the Undead (*CD* 87) allows a good cleric, instead of making a turning check then rolling turning damage (*PH* 159-60), to inflict 1d6 points of damage per cleric level to undead within 30 ft. Undead creatures make a Will save *versus* DC of 10 + the cleric's level + the cleric's Charisma modifier; success means the undead creature takes half damage.

The the supernatural ability greater turning (i.e. the granted power of the the [sun Domain](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/clericDomains.htm#sunDomain) (*PH* 188) and the radiant servant of Pelor's special ability extra greater turning (*CD* 52)) renders undead that would be turned instead destroyed.

**Different Options**
The DM has several choices when deciding how greater turning interacts with the Variant Turning Rules. For example, when the cleric uses a greater turning attempt, undead creatures may...

- make saving throws for half damage, yet the damage is maximized.
- suffer the cleric's level in additional points of damage.<sup>1</sup>
- not make saving throws for half damage.
- not make saving throws for half damage *and* the damage is maximized.

I'd lean toward the first option. The saving throw DC *versus* the effect scales directly with cleric level, making it valuable until the game's end, especially against the hordes of undead creatures it seems most appropriate to take out with such an ability. Further, it enables the turning-focused cleric to have a maximize turning effect even though there is *no* feat Maximize Supernatural Ability (there exists, however, the feats Empower Supernatural Ability (*ToM* 73) and Empower Turning (*CD* 81)). Remaining options are either too little, obviate the impressive saving throw DC, or too powerful except in a very high optimization game, respectively.<sup>2</sup>

---

1. Borrowed from *Pathfinder*'s [sun Domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/sun-domain)'s supernatural ability sun's blessing, but clerics with this ability in that game inflict this bonus damage with all their uses of channel energy.
2. An undead creature capable of casting the 4th-level Clr spell *life ward* [abjur] (*SpC* 131) still won't care, though.

Answer (score 0):

As an Alternate rule they are not flushed out and did not consult every class or ability in the game before they designed those alternate rules that is why they are only their for GM's who wish to change the elements of the game to more fit the different worlds that might be played, their is no easy answer to your question but their are many ways you could convert that rule to those alternate ways but it will be your rule not a written by the book rule.